# How do I reveal content to only people who paid through an app, using only HTML/CSS/Javascript for a Phonegap/ Cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap

I'm wanting to allow people to pay to reveal additional content within an app. I'm kind of new to this, and it's possible I wasn't able to find a thread that answers this. I'm planning right now to use https://github.com/idehub/react-native-billing for the billing, but how do I then attach that to the script which then reveals additional content on some pages? I imagine the logic would be something like, "If upgrade1 equals activated, then reveal content. Else hide content." But if that logic is correct, then I'm not sure exactly how I would go about coding that part. How would I code that?

I'm using HTML/ CSS/ Javascript with OnsenUI, in the future I plan to add React for the billing, and I plan to use Phonegap. I'm a bit lost right now and a point in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: You can't do this client-side. Anytime soon someone will discover how to download the content and view outside our App. Anyway... Try to think in a business model that don't need to block information.

Comment: You can do this client-side, but need to pair it with server-side content. Basically, the userid is sent to the server which has a DB that knows if the userid has access to certain content. The server returns data related to the userid access and you display that on your app.